# highlight the button clicked in kendo grid

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid which has 4 columns and one of the columns has button in it, on click of the button i display more information on the page. Is it possible to change the color/highlight the button clicked via CSS or jquery? and it should only highlight the button of the selected row not all the rows

Help needed

Comment: its probably possible but you need to show us the codes before we can tell you what you need to change to get the results you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a kendo button inside of a grid you can modify the css with the following,

```
.k-grid .k-button:active {
    background-color:orange;
}
```

Add this to your css or style within your HTML page and it will change the background color of the button within the grid once clicked.